# Can I compare the keys of two dictionaries?

Tags: c#, .net

Using C#, I want to compare two dictionaries to be specific, two dictionaries with the same keys but not same values, I found a method Comparer but I'm not quite sure how can I use it? Is there a way other than iterating through each key?

```
Dictionary
[
    {key : value}
]

Dictionary1
[
    {key : value2}
]
```

Comment: not really sure what you want to achieve... do you want to find the keys which are in Dictionary1 and not dictionary2 ? or the keys that are in both but have different values ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If all you want to do is see if the keys are different but not know what they are, you can use the `SequenceEqual` extension method on the `Keys` property of each dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary1;
Dictionary<string,string> dictionary2;
var same = dictionary1.Count == dictionary2.Count && dictionary1.Keys.SequenceEqual(dictionary2.Keys);
```

If you want the actual differences, something like this:

```
var keysDictionary1HasThat2DoesNot = dictionary1.Keys.Except(dictionary2.Keys);
var keysDictionary2HasThat1DoesNot = dictionary2.Keys.Except(dictionary1.Keys);
```

Comment: a) The Count comparison is redundant, since SequenceEqual does that. b) SequenceEqual can't be used with Dictionary because it requires that the keys be in the same order. It might work in some cases, but will fail if keys have been added and deleted.

Comment: dictionary.Keys does not preserve the order of the keys. This does not work.

Answer (score 9):

```
return dict1.Count == dict2.Count && 
       dict1.Keys.All(dict2.ContainsKey);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you added an explanation to go along with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public bool SameKeys<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> one, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> two)
{
    if (one.Count != two.Count) 
        return false;
    foreach (var key in one.Keys)
    {
        if (!two.ContainsKey(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think your if statement should be `one.Count != two.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a collection of the keys and index it, if that helps.

```
dictionary1.keys[0] == dictionary2.keys[5]
```

I'm actually not sure if you index it with a number or if you do it with the key itself, so try out both.

Comment: They are indexed with a number, but it's "Keys" with a capital letter. Also, that would require iterating though each keys, thing he wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with this (depending if you want the intersect or the exclusion):

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
Dictionary<int, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

IEnumerable<int> keys1ExceptKeys2 = dict1.Keys.Except(dict2.Keys);
IEnumerable<int> keys2ExceptKeys1 = dict2.Keys.Except(dict1.Keys);
IEnumerable<int> keysIntersect = dict1.Keys.Intersect(dict2.Keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just:

```
new HashSet<TKey>(dictionary1.Keys).SetEquals(dictionary2.Keys)
```

Be careful if `dictionary1` uses a different comparer from `dictionary2`. You'll have to decide whether "equality" means what one or the other dictionary thinks it means (or something else entirely)...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fastest way to check the differences between keys apart from count.

```
var isTrue = !dict1.Keys.Any(k => !dict2.Keys.Contains(k)) &&
                         !dict2.Keys.Any(k => !dict1.Keys.Contains(k));
```